# Xcode: Can't create Developer ID Application button greyed out

Tags: xcode, macos, sign

So I'm trying to sign an Electron app and I need the `Developer ID Application`.

The problem is that in Xcode the button is greyed out:

[image]

Why is it greyed out?

Can I get the Developer ID Application by other means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I'm part of a team and only the AGENT account can create the `Developer ID Application`.

So I logged in with the Apple ID of the agent in Xcode and now the button was clickable.

The only resource I've found online that explains this comes from Mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Signing_Mozilla_apps_for_Mac_OS_X

> If the "Developer ID" radio button is greyed out you probably have a group account. These types of accounts only allow for the "Agent" role to create Developer IDs.

Neither Apple's docs nor Xcode inform the user about this. Again Apple making things as difficult as possible for the developers.